Problem with installing and BitLocker
I have a new HP Envy x360 laptop that I want to put Ubuntu on. When I got through the installation, I told it to get rid of Windows, but the next instruction says to disable BitLocker. It should not be saying that. I tried to go back to do the disable anyway, but it's apparently done something to BitLocker, because I get an error trying to reboot to Windows. It wants the password for BitLocker to fix things, but I don't have that. I can't even remember if I had to give it one when I first turned on the computer.
I see on another thread that if Windows is hibernated, it could have problems. I don't think I hibernated Windows. I just held down the off switch until everything seemed to be off. Then restarted with the flash drive and pressing the Esc key to get into the BIOS.
ETA: Yes, it's near the beginning of the installation. One screen has the option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu". I check that and the next screen says I need to turn off BitLocker.
ETA: I'm installing 24.04 LTS amd64. I'd like to go back to Windows, but that no longer boots. I suspect I'll have to get a recovery disk or something to boot it and fix things up.
Sorry about that. Desktop.

"When I got through the installation, I told it to get rid of the Windows," That option is near the beginning of the install, not the end. So it's unclear what you did or how you did it or if there was simply a mistranslation. Please edit your question to clarify.

You mention Ubuntu (which has various product & installers) but give no clues as to which exact installer/system you're talking about. Please be clear with details.  You also mentioning an unclean shutdown (holding power button off) which could mean an unclean file-system (just as hibernate leaves the system) that could be misread by installer.  You should cleanly shutdown any installed OS on your device  (this includes fastboot off/disabled; as that is a hibernate feature and not a full shutdown)

You have to unlock BitLocker first. If you don't have a password, then you have to use BitLocker backup key to decrypting the BitLocker encryption. If you saved your BitLocker backup key on your PC. BLR Bitlocker recovery tool help to find it.
If you haven't saved Backup key, there is no chance of disabling the encryption. For disabling encryption, the password and backup key play a crucial role.
In the next picture, you will see how you can disable encryption with the help of a password and backup key.

